# Duplicate Inboxes on iPhone Mail — How to get rid of?

Tags: iphone, email

On my Mail application, I have 2 accounts configured — Work (Account 1 in the screenshot) and Outlook.

For some reason, the application shows duplicate inboxes for both of the accounts. I have clicked on ‘Edit’ and de-selected the duplicate inboxes (to hide them) but they keep re-appearing! How can I get rid of these duplicate inboxes?

[image]